# Tikz error with simple Lineplot with legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I try to plot a line from the file "aLinePlot.tex" which is automatically generated via matlab2tikz:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\fwidth,
height=0.75\fwidth,
at={(0\fwidth,0\fwidth)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={xLabel},
ymin=-0.4,
ymax=1.5,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={yLabel},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, legend cell align=left, align=left, legend plot pos=left, draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=black, line width=1.0pt, mark=o, mark options={solid, black}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.05\\
2   0.1\\
3   0.15\\
4   0.2\\
5   0.25\\
6   0.3\\
7   0.35\\
8   0.4\\
9   0.45\\
10  0.5\\
};
\addlegendentry{legend1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

With the following minimal Example I get the error "Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize },
        label style={font=\footnotesize },
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},  
        legend style={font=\miniscule},                     
}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\fwidth
\newlength\fheight % not used in this example

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \setlength{\fwidth}{.7\linewidth} 
            \input{aLinePlot.tex}
            \label{fig:someLabel}
            \caption{some Caption}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As i am not really familiar with tikz, can someone give me a hint how to solve this problem?
Btw: Compiler is PdfLatex on a linux machine

Comment: the problem is the line : `legend style={font=\miniscule}` I commented out that line and your code compiles fine on my debian/GNU Linux with pdflatex (using version pdftex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17)

Comment: I also searched for that  command and found that is available in `memoir` documentclass but not in article... Tested  and work within memoir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor doesn't help you when it parses the `.log` file, the error says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@textfont ->\miniscule 

l.73 \end{axis}

?
```

which means that `\miniscule` is the undefined control sequence.

`\miniscule` is a font size switch that isn't defined in the standard classes, but it is defined in the `memoir` class. So either change the documentclass to `memoir`, or modify

```
legend style={font=\miniscule}
```

to for example

```
legend style={font=\tiny}
```

Working code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir} % <-- changed article to memoir
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize },
        label style={font=\footnotesize },
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},  
        legend style={font=\miniscule},                     
}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\fwidth
\newlength\fheight % not used in this example

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \setlength{\fwidth}{.7\linewidth} 
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\fwidth,
height=0.75\fwidth,
at={(0\fwidth,0\fwidth)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={xLabel},
ymin=-0.4,
ymax=1.5,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={yLabel},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, legend cell align=left, align=left, legend plot pos=left, draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=black, line width=1.0pt, mark=o, mark options={solid, black}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.05\\
2   0.1\\
3   0.15\\
4   0.2\\
5   0.25\\
6   0.3\\
7   0.35\\
8   0.4\\
9   0.45\\
10  0.5\\
};
\addlegendentry{legend1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
            \label{fig:someLabel}
            \caption{some Caption}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    % This file was created by matlab2tikz.
    %
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.17969,0.54297,0.33984}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.00000,0.53125,0.21484}%
    \definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.36719,0.23438,0.59766}%
    \definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.78906,0.00000,0.12500}%
    \definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.52734,0.80469,0.91797}%
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[%
            width=0.951\figW,
            height=\figH,
            at={(0\figW,0\figH)},
            scale only axis,
            bar shift auto,
            clip=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,
            xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
            xlabel={Patch Retrieval mAP [\%]},
            y dir=reverse,
            ymin=0.6,
            ymax=2.4,
            ytick={1,2},
            yticklabels={{\textbackslash{}orb},{\textbackslash{}sift}},
            axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
            ]
            \addplot[xbar, bar width=0.8, fill=mycolor1, draw=white!20!black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
                41.9548209460414    2\\
            };
            \addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
                0   0.6\\
                0   2.4\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data1}
            
            \node[right, align=left]
            at (axis cs:101,2) {41.95\%};
            \addplot [color=mycolor2, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor2, mycolor2}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                64.7063703472285    2\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data2}
            
            \addplot [color=mycolor3, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor3, mycolor3}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                38.1802387463562    2\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data3}
            
            \addplot [color=mycolor4, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor4, mycolor4}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                22.9778537445396    2\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data4}
            
            \addplot[xbar, bar width=0.8, fill=mycolor5, draw=white!20!black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
                29.2544208148136    1\\
            };
            \addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
                0   0.6\\
                0   2.4\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data5}
            
            \node[right, align=left]
            at (axis cs:101,1) {29.25\%};
            \addplot [color=mycolor2, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor2, mycolor2}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                50.0597027132659    1\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data6}
            
            \addplot [color=mycolor3, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor3, mycolor3}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                24.2959181262745    1\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data7}
            
            \addplot [color=mycolor4, draw=none, mark size=1.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid, fill=black!60!mycolor4, mycolor4}]
            table[row sep=crcr]{%
                13.4076416049004    1\\
            };
            \addlegendentry{data8}
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Undefined control sequence. ]

Comment: Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}